# How can I send local file as fax using twilio api in python?

Tags: python, twilio, fax

I am new to twilio and python. I want to build a simple fax command using twilio api. So I use this and it worked perfectly

```
 fax = client.fax.faxes \
.create(
     from_="+18566198960",
     media_url="https://www.twilio.com/docs/documents/25/justthefaxmaam.pdf",
     to="+14105210871"
 )

print(fax.sid)
```

however, I want to change the media_url to a local file located in doc folder so I use this media_url

```
 media_url="../doc/testfax.doc"
```

but I get this error

> > HTTP Error Your request was:
> >
> > POST /Faxes
> >
> > Twilio returned the following information:
> >
> > Unable to create record: Parameter 'MediaUrl' is invalid
> >
> > More information may be available here:
> >
> > https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20001

how can I assign a local file as the fax content to send?

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at the Twilio API for sending a Fax - https://www.twilio.com/docs/fax/send

It requires:

```
* A destination phone number or SIP URI.
* A From number - this can be either an Incoming Phone Number or an Outgoing  Caller ID. (Optional for SIP destinations.)
* A URL which points to the media that will be sent via fax (currently, this must be a PDF file; see our security page for information on how to ensure the request for your media comes from Twilio).
```

The API does not support a local file (only a URL, with a PDF file).

Comment: is there a way to upload my pdf file to twilio, and then get the twilio url for the pdf?

Comment: Uploading a FAX / PDF file to Twilio is not the correct approach.

Comment: Uploading a FAX / PDF file to Twilio is not the correct approach.  You want to be able to have control of where your files are uploaded to.  Access control - the ability to delete / remove them afterwards.    I would use AWS to upload you FAX to an S3 bucket.  Make the PDF public, and use the URL within the Twilio API.

Comment: Twillio even did not works with pre signed aws s3 urls of a pdf file